# elasticsearch index vs type strategy

Tags: elasticsearch, metadata, data-modeling, elasticsearch-2.0, metadata-repository

I'm kind of new to elasticsearch, and would really appreciate the help,

in my company we have a metadata repository,
the repository is structured this way:
we have groups of entities of different types, lets say

```
entitiesGroupA: [Aentity1, Aentity2, Aentity3...],
entitiesGroupB: [Bentity1, Bentity2, Bentity3...]
```

about 15 groups, and in total about 1500 entities 
each entity name is unique, and there are no duplicates 
there is basic data for each entity (flags, text description, and more) 
for each entity there are aproximatly 100~ fields on average.

when i say field I dont mean the basic data, I mean a logical field in the entity that each field contains things like boolean flags, text description, and so on...
there are also groups for the fields (about 5)

moreover the repository has versions, every month a new version

**the question is**, what is the best way to model this structure to **fit best in elasticsearch**


the usage of the data in elasticsearch will be to search entities by name and by group,
retrieve all the fields of an entity, search fields by name and by group, search fields in an entity by name and by group,

i thought of the following model:

```
/entities_[Version]/[entityGroup]/[entityName]
```

will have data on the entity (not its fields)

e.g: version 1 of the repository, entity1 from groupA

```
/entities_1/groupA/entity1
```

the fields of each entity will be as follows

```
/[entityName]_[Version]/[fieldGroup]/[fieldName]
```

e.g: version 1 of entity1, field1 from field group A

```
/entity1_1/groupA/field1
```

Is this a good way to model the repository?, I feel that in this way I create allot of indexes, maybe i should model it to have more types? what are the advantages for more indexes instead of more types?

as you can see, because Im new to elasticsearch and I couldn't find allot of studying material I feel a bit clueless O:

thanks for any help :D

Comment: Definitely read through https://www.elastic.co/blog/index-vs-type

Comment: i read it, still kinda feels vague, like how much is 'many documents for each type'?

Comment: The mere fact that each group has many entities and each entity can have 100+ fields would call for a one index per entity approach, simply because of the fact that the odds are high that two different entities might have two fields with the same name but different types, and this is not allowed. Even if that's not the case yet, you might introduce a new field with the same name in two different entities residing in the same index, and you'll get into trouble. I'm just shooting in the dark, though, it would really help to have some concrete examples.

Comment: Also note that the group name could well be a simple text field in your entities instead of an index or mapping type.